# Is it possible to explicitly declare compound labels in the package chemnum?

Tags: chemistry, chemnum

Is there a command in the `chemnum` package that allows labels for a compound to be explicitly defined (for example, if I explicitly wanted a compound to be called `A3` or another string), similar to the command `\declarecompound` in the `chemcompounds` package? In a different question the package author said that this was possible but I have not been able to find it in the most recent documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with a little effort:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\makeatletter
\newcmpdcounterformat{gobble}{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cmpd{foo1},
\cmpd{foo1}

\cmpd[pre-label-code=xx,post-label-code=yy]{foo2},
\cmpd{foo2}

\cmpd[pre-label-code=aa,post-label-code=bb,counter-format=gobble]{foo3},
\cmpd{foo3}

\cmpd{foo4},
\cmpd{foo4}

\cmpd{foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this workaround the actual *label* is empty and the pre- and post-code are used as label.

---

With an up to date version of `chemnum` (v1.2 2016/04/14 – should be available on CTAN already) a more direct way is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}[2016/04/14]

\ExplSyntaxOn
% this only works for main labels!
\NewDocumentCommand \declarecmpd {O{}mm}
  {
    \chemnum_compound_if_defined:nF {#2}
      { \chemnum_define_compound:n {#2} }
    \chemnum_compound_set_property:nnn {#2} {counter-representation} {#3}
    \chemnum_declare_compound:nn {#1} {#2}
    \chemnum_finalize_compound:n {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cmpd{foo1}

\cmpd+{foo2}

\declarecmpd{foo2}{AA}

\cmpd{foo1,foo2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, this seems unusually difficult. Given that `chemnum` seems to be an overall improvement over `chemcompounds`, was there a reason why you chose to forgo writing a new command to replace `\declarecompound`?

Comment: @Anthony `chemnum` exists since March 2014 and I can't remember that anyone ever wanted or needed the feature – it just didn't seem necessary.

Comment: Occasionally I find `\declarecompound` useful when I need a compound label to match some existing reports (perhaps a single 'A' label outside of a main sequence of Arabic numerals) or would like the label to be an abbreviation or acronym specific to a compound (such as when I would like a compound to be called `ATP` rather than just a numeral), though I do understand if others may mostly find it unnecessary.

Comment: I've wrapped it up into an `xparse`/LaTeX3 command in case I might need it again, though others may find it useful: `% Defining compound labels
\makeatletter
\newcmpdcounterformat{gobble}{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\declarecmpd}{om}{
 \IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {\cmpd*{#2}}
  {\cmpd*[pre-label-code=#1,counter-format=gobble]{#2}}
}`

Comment: @Anthony I've added a second way which probably suits your needs better.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! Another reason (probably the more important one) I've found the need for an explicit `\declarecmpd` or `\declarecompound` is to match with "finalized" figures with existing labels (rather than replacing them through `\replacecmpd`). Would you let me know if you have plans to include the `\declarecmpd` in a future update of the package? Thank you gain.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to work when using `\cmpd+`; the labels revert back to Arabic numerals

Comment: @Anthony yes, you're right – the label is hardwired into `chemnum`. I'll need to make some internal changes for this to work reliably…

Comment: @Anthony I'll update `chemnum` tonight or yesterday and will update my answer once the new version is officially updated and on CTAN.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorry to trouble you with this

Comment: @Anthony the update is there. I updated my answer accordingly